# How to delete cassandra rowkey

Tags: cassandra, hector

I use cassandra in my project, and it is not distributed, now I write some junit test, and I want clear my database after finished every test, but the rowkey can not be deleted? can you tell me how to delete cassandra rowkey.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To clear all data from a column family you should use truncate. You can do this from cassandra-cli:

```
[default@unknown] use ks;
Authenticated to keyspace: ks
[default@ks] truncate cf;
```

Answer (score 3):

With Hector to you do:

```
Mutator<K> = HFactory.createMutator(keyspace, Serializer<K>);
mutator.addDeletion(key, columnFamilyName);
mutator.execute();
```

where K is the TYPE of your row

Comment: @doandhuyhai stills rowkey remains